# Overlay with max width and percentage

Tags: html, css

Would like to find a way to add a div with position fixed and max width, that should be placed either in a div with overlay or outside overlay. But the tricky part is that, when the window is scaled, I would like it to adjust per percentage....

So if I have a div with max width of 800px but when I make the browser window smaller, it should shrink. Is this possible for all browsers?

Or do I have to use a plugin for this, like jqModal? Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just define a `max-width`, and then use percentages for scaling purposes:

```
.modal {
    width: 50%;
    max-width: 800px
}
```

Comment: I was writing the same answer, but this seems so trivial that I find it hard to believe this is the requested problem...